# Verificar se a webview está carregada

Tags: android, webview

Preciso verificar se a webview está carregada para poder executar uma função javascript que se encontra na webview, mas não sei como verificar se a webview já está carregada 100%.

segue o código:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://meusite.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode implementar o [onPageFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) da classe [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 

     } 
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Vitor.